# Php isset in html

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a simple isset condition in my html with php like this :

```
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
        <tr><td><?php print t('Adresse :'); ?> : </td><td><?php print $participant->adresse1; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td><?php print t(''); ?> : </td><td><?php print $participant->code_postal.' '.$participant->ville; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td><?php print t(''); ?> : </td><td><?php print $participant->pays; ?></td></tr>
        <?php if(isset($participant->tel_perso)): ?><tr><td><?php print t('Tél :'); ?> : </td><td><?php print $participant->tel_perso; ?></td></tr><?php endif; ?>
        <tr><td><?php print t('Email :'); ?> : </td><td><?php print $participant->email_id; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td><?php print t('Date de naissance :'); ?> : </td><td><?php print format_date($participant->date_naissance, "custom", "d F Y") ?></td></tr>
 </table>
```

The problem is that this row is always show, even  if the isset return false (I test it in the code before and it works)

WHy it's not working in html ?

Comment: Why have you `:` after your condition ?

Comment: Because of `endif;` I guess

Comment: @Flyzzx Check `endif` in PHP.

Comment: Oh didn't see, try to use the standard way with `{}`

Comment: Exactly, when a mixture of HTML is involved, it's always better. @Flyzzx

Comment: in this case `endif;` is a valid choice; It keeps your code readable if you don't want to use `echo` to print html elements but just escape the html by closing your PHP tags. +1 for using endif here.

Comment: Yes, I never use endif personnaly

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Why is that always better?

Comment: @kerbholz Readability? And see the reply to your comment on my answer. It's primarily opinion based, but it definitely works for me. Or, may be a syntax error when parsing the alternate `:` way.

Comment: @kerbholz When we have an else, it doesn't work.

Comment: To get back to the actual question (instead discussing preferred coding styles), your HTML seems off. You have `</tr>` inside the `if`, but I don't see the opening `<tr>` or `<td>` inside the `if`. Can you show us a few rows before and after this line as well, so we see the context?

Comment: I edited with all my table

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `$participant->tel_perso` is either not defined at all or actual contains `null`? If it is something else, like `false`, empty string etc, `isset()` will return true. `isset()` only returns `false` if the variable/property does not exist at all or is `null`. In this case, you might want to try `if (!empty($participant->tel_perso))` instead. That does the same as `isset()` but also returns true for any "falsy" value (like empty string etc).

Comment: It's empty i think, but when I try the isset in my code before the html the isset return me false (so the variable is not set no ?)

Comment: Try with `!empty()` instead of `isset()` and see if it changes anything. Where does the data come from? Database? When using databases and you have a column that is nullable, it can first be null when you create a new row (and don't define a value for that column). If you then update the row from a form (with an input for that column), it can be set as an empty string instead. It's still empty, but `isset()` would change from `false` to `true`.

Comment: Also... _"It's empty i think"_ - You need to know this. Do a var_dump() and check the value. Before posting here and asking why things doesn't work, you need to be 100% sure about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be because your value was set, but it didn't have a value that you wished to show. Without knowing what that value is, perhaps an [`empty`](http://php.net/empty) call would be better for you. Displaying only the content when it's NOT `!` [`empty`](http://php.net/empty). If that's not working for you, check what the variable is set to with [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) and comment back here.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><?=t('Adresse :')?></td>
        <td><?=$participant->adresse1?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?=t('')?> :</td>
        <td><?=$participant->code_postal.' '.$participant->ville?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?=print t('')?> :</td>
        <td><?=$participant->pays;?></td>
    </tr>
<?php   if (!empty($participant->tel_perso))):   ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=t('Tél :')?></td>
        <td><?=$participant->tel_perso;?></td>
    </tr>
<?php   endif;  ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=t('Email :')?></td>
        <td><?=$participant->email_id;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?=t('Date de naissance :')?></td>
        <td><?=format_date($participant->date_naissance, "custom", "d F Y")?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your if-condition to this:

```
if(isset($participant->tel_perso) && $participant->tel_perso)
```

If yout 'tel_perso' returns false, the value is set, so you need to check for 
not false' as well.

Prefered way would be to use:

```
if(!empty($participant->tel_perso))
```

Like @Magnus Eriksson said, because empty() would be a valid usage here.

```
The following values are considered to be empty:

"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
```

Comment: ...or just do: `if (!empty($participant->tel_perso)):`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Indeed, was just about to edit the answer with a reference to your comment.